# Community Moderation Plugin for Comments

Tags: comments, plugin-recommendation, moderation

Is there any wordpress plugin that allows the community to moderate the comments by themselves in Slashdot style?

I found a plugin that allows the visitors to like or dislike the comments. But it doesn't provide any moderation functionality beyond collecting the ratings. I would like to be able to set rules based on these ratings such as whether a comment will be hidden. The plugin should also manage the reputations of the commenters in Stackexchange style.